# Redifiniton of variable with a different type

Tags: c++, redefinition

I am getting the following error on Xcode: regarding my variable "in_code" and my class "Game_Object"

Redefinition of 'in_code' with a difference type 'Game_Object' vs 'char'

Here is my constructor for Person, another class

```
Person::Person(char in_code)
{
Game_Object(in_code);     -> HERE IS WHERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR!!

speed = 5;

cout << "Person constructed"<<endl;

}
```

However my constructor for Game object is declared to get char variables. See that:

```
Game_Object::Game_Object(char in_code)
{
display_code = in_code;
state = 's';
id_num = 0;
location = Cart_Point();
cout<<"Game_Object constructed."<<endl;
```

Can you help please?

Comment: `Game_Object obj(in_code);`

Comment: Shall we start by assuming `Game_Object` is the base class of `Person` and you accidentally put it in the body of the `Person` constructor rather than the initialization list were it belongs? Unrelated: `location = Cart_Point();` is useless if the member is declared `Cart_Point location;` in the class def. It is already constructed with that very default. In fact, I see no reason *all* of the other assignments in that constructor are not in the initialization list of `Game_Object`, with only `cout << ...` being in the actual body.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Game_Object` is a base class of `Person`, you should write the constructor like this:

```
Person::Person(char in_code):Game_Object(in_code)
{

speed = 5;

cout << "Person constructed"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: +1 And if it is *not* the base class, the `Game_Object(in_code);` line itself is useless and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too. I figured it out.
But firstly I gotta write some theory for easier understanding.
There are two features in C++ that implicitly create extra code during compile time:

1) copy constructor and copy assignment operator are created by compiler if you do not specify them for your class. In implementation part it copies every member recursively.

2) if you have a constructor with one parameter of any type then compiler also creates an assignment operator with the same parameter. In implementation part it creates new instance of your type and assigns it your variable.

It is illustrated in example code below:

```
class GameObject{
public:
    GameObject(int iD):innerData(iD){
        //..
    }
    int innerData;
};

//  Create a new object using constuctor specified by me..
GameObject gameObject(5);
std::cout<<"gameObject = "<<gameObject.innerData<<std::endl;

//  Create the second object with different data..
GameObject gameObject2(6);
std::cout<<"gameObject2 = "<<gameObject2.innerData<<std::endl;

//  Next line compiles well cause compiler created
//  GameObject& operator=(const GameObject&) for us.
gameObject2=gameObject;
std::cout<<"gameObject2 = "<<gameObject2.innerData<<std::endl;

//  Next line also compiles well cause compiler created
//  GameObject& operator=(int iD) using GameObject(int iD)
//  as a reference.
gameObject2=3;
std::cout<<"gameObject2 = "<<gameObject2.innerData<<std::endl;
```

Of course you are able to specify your own copy constructors and copy assignment operators or use a 'delete' (presented in C++11) keyword to remove an ability of coping any instance of your class.
More about 'delete' in C++11 you can find [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#default).

So in your case compiler cannot decide what constructor you actually call  in

```
Game_Object(in_code);
```

line cause there are two options: either you call Game_Object(char) constructor or you call Game_Object(Game_Object(char)) constructor. This can sound silly but these constructions are different for compiler.

So all you need to resolve your issue is to specify explicitly type of your parameter with a typecast operator

```
Person::Person(char in_code)
{
Game_Object(char(in_code));    

speed = 5;

cout << "Person constructed"<<endl;

}
```

Good luck with C++ and sorry for ugly formatting.